# What exactly is this command doing?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

This line of code is working perfect but I don't really have a good grasp of what it actually is doing:

```
df['New_Column1'], shrink['New_Column2'] = zip(*df['Original_Column'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-', 1)))
```

This is basically splitting a column up to the point where there is a dash which separates the Employee ID number and their actual name (in the original data they are combined in one column).

Is this the most efficient way to do this? And how would I describe this to someone? I never used the 'zip' function before and I am not 100% with lambda either but I use it sometimes to change date formats.

Answer (score 2):

The `apply` method calls the lambda function once for each row of the Series,
`df['Original Column']`. Calling a Python function once for each row is a recipe
for slowness (if the Series has many rows). In general, to maximize performance
using Pandas, only use the `apply` method if there is no other option.

The use of `zip` here compounds the inefficency. `zip` returns a Python list
of tuples. Python lists and tuples require a lot more space than a Pandas Series
when the values inside the Series are of a native NumPy dtype. Strings can be
represented by a native NumPy dtype, so keeping the data in a Series is more
space-efficient. So `zip`, like `apply`, should be avoided here if possible.

In this case, you could instead of Panda's [vectorized string method, `extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Original':['abc-def']*3+['foo']})
#   Original
# 0  abc-def
# 1  abc-def
# 2  abc-def
# 3      foo

df[['New1', 'New2']] = df['Original'].str.extract(r'([^-]*)-?(.*)')
print(df)
```

yields

```
  Original New1 New2
0  abc-def  abc  def
1  abc-def  abc  def
2  abc-def  abc  def
3      foo  foo
```

The argument to `extract` is a regex pattern.
`r'([^-]*)-?(.*)'` has the following meaning:

```
([^-]*)     match 0-or-more characters other than a literal hyphen
-?          match 0-or-1 literal question mark
(.*)        match 0-or-more of any character
```

The patterns surrounded by parentheses define groups which are then returned by the
`extract` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, *This is basically splitting a column up to the point where there is a dash which separates the Employee ID number and their actual name (in the original data they are combined in one column).*

I'll give you a little run through of what `zip` and `lambda` do:

[**`zip`**<sup>from the docs</sup>](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

**Example**:

```
>>> my_list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> my_list2 = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
>>> zip(my_list1, my_list2) #Returns a list of tuples, each tuple has a number corresponding to its number vowel.
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'e'), (3, 'i'), (4, 'o'), (5, 'u')]
>>>
```

[**`lambda`**<sup>from the docs</sup>](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

> Small anonymous functions can be created with the lambda keyword. This function returns the sum of its two arguments: lambda a, b: a+b

**Example**:

```
>>> #Writing a function that squares numbers
>>>
>>> #Long way 
>>> def square(x):
...     return x**2
... 
>>>
>>> #Short way 
>>> square = lambda x: x**2
>>>
```